# How to remove the MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0 from header when set from power query

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have a project and I upgraded from OData V3 to V4. Now when I try to connect from Power Query I get an error when trying to see the data :

```
Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Specified method is not supported. --->
Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.ErrorException: Specified method is not supported. --->
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataExpression.VisitColumnAccess(ColumnAccessQueryExpression expression) 
Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.OData.V4.ODataExpression.Visit(QueryExpression queryExpression)
```

From what I see the issue is when in the header of Power Query  **MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0** is set. If I don't have this I can get the data.

How can I remove this from the header in .NET, I use Web API and OData v4 and I call the controllers from Power Query.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem querying my ODATA v4 service from Power BI and Power Query. After digging through the source files available [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi) I found the ODataRoute supports this HasRelaxedODataVersionContraint method.

Invoke it when you declare your OData route in your WebApiConfig.cs.

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("OdataRoute", "odata", GetEdmModel()).HasRelaxedODataVersionConstraint();
```

The comments on the method make sense; Relax the version constraint. The service will allow clients to send both OData V4 and previous max version headers.  Headers for the previous max version will be ignored.

Just another example of ODATA being mismanaged due to lack of focus. I suspect the developers involved are doing it as a pet project rather than a funded core MS project.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this in ASPNET Core?